# Is Aptana still actively supported?

Tags: aptana, pydev, aptana3

Prior to this summer, Aptana and PyDev got updates every few weeks or months. I haven't seen any updates in a long time (since August 8, 2013).

Does it mean that Aptana is not being actively developed now? Or are we just waiting for a new release?

Comment: Looks like there's some activity in Aptana GitHub projects (I see some changes made 9 days ago to Python code). Still, they may have some private repositories that are pushed to GitHub during release.

Comment: Looking at recent questions here, there have been a couple of updates in the last month or two.

Comment: Yes, Aptana still active. You can check their bug tracker and see their nightly build can be update within 1 month.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about project status or future plans and not programming as defined in the [help] guidelines. Contact the project directly regarding status or plans.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Aptana 3.4.2 was last updated in August 2013. Since then, an automatic update to Aptana 3.5.0 was introduced on December 26, 2013, but was subsequently removed around January 15, 2014 as several people have reported bugs.

Also, it is easy to switch to a beta version of Aptana by taking software channels from here:
http://preview.appcelerator.com/studio/

The source: facebook post by Aptana group and comments on that https://www.facebook.com/aptana/posts/10152080073750100